# ActiveMQ command:Cannot allocate memory

Tags: jvm, activemq-classic

ActiveMQ 5.13.3 server is running normally.

But when I executed the `activemq list` command, an error occurred.

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Using incremental CMS is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release  
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO:os::commit_memory(0x0000000654cc0000, 3946053632, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
```

My question is a little different from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46801741/jvm-crashes-with-error-cannot-allocate-memory-errno-12).
I am wondering why the execution of `activemq list` command will report this error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JVM crashes with error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46801741/jvm-crashes-with-error-cannot-allocate-memory-errno-12)

Answer (score 0):

So the reason is that `activemq list` starts a new JVM, then connects to broker. The message is telling you that your box doesn't have enough memory to start this second JVM. Either add swap, or add memory to the system.

Also, `apache-activemq-5.15.9/bin/env` contains the `Xms` setting for the JVM. This is an unfortunate piece of bad "JVM Tuning Advice" from the past (JDK 1.5 days) that people blindly apply. I'd remove the `Xms` setting completely and let the JVM resize it's heap as necessary.